# Android: How do I make a non-square area of an image clickable? Additionally, some questions about image scaling

Tags: android-imageview, android-xml, clickable, image-scaling

My problem is three-fold. I'm going to try to explain as detailed as I can, because I've asked this question before and haven't gotten any clear answers.

**What I'm Trying to Do:**
I have diagonally shaped images, that I'm trying to make clickable, so I separated them out of the background image. They were originally one image, but I've cut out several pieces of the image and I want to align them identically to how they were in the original image. This might not the best method for what I am trying to achieve, and if there is a better way to make non-square areas of an image clickable, that would solve all of these problems. If not, here is my problem. The problem is, as soon as I align them in XML, I boot them up on an Android emulator or my phone, and they are aligned differently on both, differently than the preview and from each other.

Below is my example, and I'll try to explain what I mean.

[image: correct]

The black and white grid is my background. The brown, red, and yellow lines are separate images. I don't want to just combine them with the background, because I need those lines to be clickable. I'd set a button behind them, but they are diagonally shaped and I need the entire shape to be clickable. However, they have to be EXACTLY where they are in the background, aligned specifically as they are to the background. The problem is, as soon as I load it on another device, it scales, and everything misaligns.

[image: Incorrect Example]

It also misaligns depending the device, so I presume it's because it's scaling the different parts differently.

I need a way to align it the way I want it, and have each image scale together.

**How I've Been Trying This So Far:**
Initially, I tried just using XML. And herein was my first problem. My background image is 1920x1080. It loads on the emulator without a problem. However, if I try to load it on my phone, I get the following error:

> OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (5760x3240, max=4096x4096)

So that leads to my first question. Why is my 1920x1080 trying to load as 5760x3240?!

I bypassed this, by using Picasso to scale the image to 1920x1080. As a sidenote, in addition to programmatically loading the image, I also am removing the title bar. Here is my OnCreate:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout);



    Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.backgroundimage).resize(1920,1080).into((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.background));
```

On the XML side, I've tried all sorts of different things. Relative layouts, linear layouts, frame layouts...None seem to scale the separate imageviews the same.

Which leads to my second question.

How do I scale two differently sized imageviews together, so that they maintain their alignment on different sized devices?

My second imageview is 198x547(this would be the equivalent of one of the squiggly lines in the example images) and even setting that in Picasso does not maintain my alignment. In fact, that doesn't seem to work at all, since I have to scale it differently to even match the alignment I have in the original image.

**Summary Questions**

1. I need a diagonally shaped portion of an image to be clickable. Is cutting the shape out as a separate image the appropriate method for doing so? If not, how do I make such a specific, non-square area of an image clickable?
2. I need specific alignments to scale together. Why aren't they?
3. Why does my png file upscale itself?